# Apache server not allowing mime type

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, lamp, html5

How does one set mime types in Ubuntu 12.10 for `.mp4` and `.ogv` video rendering?
I want to run simple video files through localhost. Please give suggestions.

I have kept these 3 lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

But when I run the index.html page from `localhost/Ubuntu/index.html` path its not running the video. I have used html5 tags for running video. Now, what could be the issue? I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Lamp server.

Comment: What mime type is returned in requests for these files? Did you restart the server after making the changes you describe?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in `httpd`'s logs (error log: `/var/log/apache2/error_log`, access log: `/var/log/apache/access_log`) should shed some light.

Also to verify that MIME types are getting set in responses, you can do: `curl -I http://localhost/path/to/file.ogv`, and you'll get MIME type in `Content-Type` response header.